# Creating a TeXForm/TraditionalForm/etcForm - like function

Tags: front-end, output-formatting

How could we go about creating a function that behaves like those?

After a while thinking, my best try is with `CellPrint` printing an `Output` cell with the famous `CellLabel` of Out[blah]//myForm. This solution is good enough for me for now, but I'm using it as an excuse to understand all these issues better... This mimics the behaviour, its not the same... For example, you have to manually get the `$Line`, you get the `GeneratedCell` option to `True`, and I don't know what else I'm missing. In fact, the kernel actually doesn't seem to do anything in the real form functions. So this solution would behave wrongly, for example, if I wrapped it other things... `FullForm[myForm[stuff]]` should return `myForm[stuff]` in a FullForm-tagged cell..

Comment: For extending TeXForm (rather than creating a completely new one), there's some useful information [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/exporting-notebook-to-html-using-conversion-rules).

Answer (score 4):

This is *far* from fully integrated into the system but it is a first order approximation of the behavior of other forms.  Perhaps it will inspire someone else with a better method.

```
formfunc =
  StringReplace[
    ToString @ #,
    {"[" -> "(", "]" -> ")", x : DigitCharacter .. :> "-->" <> x <> "<--"}
  ] &;

MakeBoxes[myForm[expr_], StandardForm] := 
  InterpretationBox[#, expr] & @ ToBoxes @ formfunc @ expr

ToString[expr_, myForm] ^:= formfunc[expr]
```

This provides output that can be re-evaluated to recover the original expression:

```
2^(1/2) // myForm
```

> ```
> "Sqrt(-->2<--)"
> ```

This produces a normal String:

```
ToString[2^(1/2), myForm]
```

> ```
> "Sqrt(-->2<--)"
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This might be of help:

> $OutputForms is a list of the formatting functions that get stripped
>   off when wrapped around the output.

```
$OutputForms= {InputForm,OutputForm,TextForm,CForm,Short,Shallow,MatrixForm,TableForm,TreeForm,FullForm,NumberForm,EngineeringForm,ScientificForm,QuantityForm,PaddedForm,AccountingForm,BaseForm,DisplayForm,StyleForm,FortranForm,MathMLForm,TeXForm,StandardForm,TraditionalForm}
```

I recently discovered [while working](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51968/16267) on a way to better show rational matrices.

Comment: They include the PrintForms which include the BoxForms. I did some digging at the time. Thanks! I think the output forms are those heads that end up showing applied to the cell label such as in mma`Out[34]//InputForm`. Try `Unprotect@$OutputForms;AppendTo[$OutputForms, la]; la[5]`

Comment: @Rojo Nice!  I tried to figure out those cell tags once and failed.  Handy!  Thanks, unlikely.

Comment: unlikely, this solves something I wondered about for a while: [(44189)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44189/121) -- you can now answer this question.  Please do so!

Answer (score 1):

Understanding now that you want to define a completely new format, but still not sure what you want that format to look like, perhaps this does what you want:

```
Format[myForm[x_]] := {x, x}
x = blah;
y = myForm[x]
Head[y]
```

> ```
> {blah,blah}
> myForm
> ```

Note that the result printed as `{blah,blah}` but the `Head` of the result is `myForm`.

**First attempt**

I'm not sure exactly how you want `myForm` to behave but the standard way to do this is to define a value of `Format`.  For example,

```
Unprotect[Log];
Format[Log[x_], TraditionalForm] := ln[x]
Protect[Log];
```

Now, `TraditionalForm[Log[x]]` will print like $ln(z)$:

[image]

Alternatively, you could define an UpValue for `Log`:

```
Unprotect[Log];
Log /: MakeBoxes[Log[x_], TraditionalForm] :=
  RowBox[{"ln", "(", MakeBoxes[x, TraditionalForm], ")"}];
Protect[Log];
```

The result should be the same.  Of course, you could do something similar of your `myForm`.

Comment: I was actually thinking of another form. In fact, the `Format` documentation suggests "You can add your own forms for formatted output. " apart from CForm, FortranForm, and friends...

Comment: @Rojo I'm not sure I understand your comment.  Does my edit help clarify?

Comment: Mark, `MakeBoxes` is assignable without the need to use UpValues.  Just use MakeBoxes[something] = somethingElse  (see the docs).  I also found it less confusing than format, but never managed to figure out either of them completely.

Comment: @Mark He means make a `MyForm` so that `ToString[expr, MyForm]` will work.  E.g. make a PythonForm which outputs things formatted correctly for Python, or something similar.

Comment: @Szabolcs I see.  Yes my suggestion is not quite sufficient.

Comment: @MarkMcClure it clarifies a little, yes. But, I'm still wondering, if I defined my own form like that `Format[_, myform]`, then how could I actually use it? (naturally, not calling Format explicitly)... For example, how would I make a function like `TraditionalForm[stuff]` that outputs as it should, with the "//myForm" in the cell label?

Comment: or the many other uses real forms have in Matheamtica... In fact, my string of doubts started when I realised that by specifying the default format type of a cell style, to either InputForm, TextForm, StandardForm, etc, you were actually defining if you would be typing in boxes or just plain strings. One thing led to the other and I soon had to accept that I barely know what forms are and the issue makes me dizzy

Comment: In fact it started when I wanted to create a form that output as some kind of tweaked TeXForm... I don't really recall, I've been having these kinds of doubts for a while