# Automatically including custom stylesheet with notebook

Tags: front-end, stylesheet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I easily eliminate the dependency of a stylesheet on a non-built-in stylesheet?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7779/how-can-i-easily-eliminate-the-dependency-of-a-stylesheet-on-a-non-built-in-styl)

For some work I am doing, I take my notes in a notebook with a custom stylesheet. For my own convenience, I have separated the styles into their own stylesheet notebook, and reference within the notebook's stylesheet like is done with `Default.nb`:

[image]

Unfortunately, this makes sharing this notebook difficult with out also ensuring that the recipient has the stylesheet already installed. Barring that, what are the alternatives?

The simplest would be if the `NotebookDirectory[]` was automatically included in the search for the stylesheets, then the stylesheet can be simply placed in that directory. This works great in the case of a shared network drive, but still requires a two step process for the case of email.

Ideally, I would like to automatically embed *all* of the style definitions up to a certain depth in the referenced stylesheets. How can this be most easily accomplished?

Comment: @rm-rf missed that. Thanks.

Comment: No problem :) $ $

Comment: @rm-rf I'd like to delete this, but it's put me in a mandatory 48 waiting period under the assumption that it may be "reopened." We both know this is not true, so will you kill it for me?

Comment: I actually don't think it's a bad idea to have it alive, because it offers another Google pathway to the question. I would probably search for "include custom stylesheet" like in yours rather than "Eliminate dependency" and your question is good fodder for the spiders. That's the single biggest advantage of well written dupes and it's a pity that a lot of them were mod culled in the past (I intend to review them soon). If you're still insistent on deleting it for some reason, then I'll oblige :)

Comment: @rm-rf reasonable argument, and I still get upvotes for this. :)