# Loading Cell Option Definitions on Kernel Launch for Stylesheets

Tags: stylesheet, contexts

I have my own stylesheet that I like using so much I change all my documents to it almost immediately, but as I demo Mathematica to people I cannot use `DefaultStyleDefinitions` as it unnecessarily confuses people. I therefore have a function (typed verbatim, not loaded) in my init.m file that pastes the definitions from a stylesheet into the `EvaluationNotebook[]`

```
BeginPackage["PasteStyles`"]
pasteStyleSheet::usage="pasteStyleSheet[stylesheet, \"Admin\"] pastes the style definitions provided by stylesheet located in $BaseDirectory (etc)"; Begin["`Private`"]
pasteStyleSheet[stylesheet_String,"Admin"]:=SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],StyleDefinitions->Get[FileNameJoin[{$BaseDirectory,"FrontEnd","StyleSheets",stylesheet<>".nb"}]]]
pasteStyleSheet[stylesheet_String,"User"]:=SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],StyleDefinitions->Get[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory,"FrontEnd","StyleSheets",stylesheet<>".nb"}]]]
pasteStyleSheet[stylesheet_String,"System"]:=SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],StyleDefinitions->Get[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,"SystemFiles","FrontEnd","StyleSheets",stylesheet<>".nb"}]]]
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

I have an issue in that I use options for cells such as `WholeCellGroupOpener` and `ReturnCreatesNewCell` that Mathematica doesn't seem to know anything about when my function is evaluated. I found this out because I used to find `$CellContext` throughout my pasted style definitions.

Currently, I have shoved the following lines into the package to make sure it works.

```
System`WholeCellGroupOpener;
System`ReturnCreatesNewCell;
```

My questions are:

- Why do I get `$CellContext` for some functions that should be on `` `System ``?
- How do I ensure my function works as intended? Does it need to live somewhere else?

Justifications:

- I need to paste the styles, as I email the notebooks out.
- I spend most of my time making fun things in the front end, I'm expecting this stylesheet to eventually become something that no one else will ever want to use.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but [here's](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7779/5) a related question that solves the same problem with using & sharing custom stylesheets (i.e. embed in notebook instead of linking to style file).

Comment: @rm-rf thanks! Changing styles with Mike's stylesheetChanger will definitely be useful for other things I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Kuba thanks for reviving this! I think that should be considered a duplicate, yes. Should I close this as duplicate? Not sure of procedure.

Comment: @MartinJohnHadley The question isn't exactly the same but the answer is the answer. If you agree with closing it will be automatically closed as a duplicate an stay here as a road sign for future visitors.

Comment: Which was my intention but it's your call :)

Comment: @Kuba Ha! I was using the mobile app and only saw the comment, didn't see the "that solved my problem" button that you get in the website proper. Yes, I'll accept.