# Merge StyleSheet into a notebook

Tags: notebooks, files-and-directories, stylesheet, save, file-transfer

I have a custom style called *style1.nb* and I want to install it into a notebook *Class01.nb* so I can send only the notebook file to my students with the style of *style1.nb*. Is that possible?

Comment: Duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7779/5

Comment: It's not the same, i made a style from empty notebook and now i want to merge the stlye in the notebook soo the stlye.nb it's not needed anymore something like Stylisher["style.nb"] run the function and then the notebook don't need the stlye file

Comment: @ Gonzalo There is a way to quench a custom style into a CDF document. Would it be of interest to you?

Comment: @Gonzalo Instead of answering your question inside the question, can you please post an answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code used by the OP to solve its issue:

```
nb=NotebookOpen[NotebookDirectory[]<>"style1.nb"];
tmp=NotebookGet[nb];
estilos=Cases[tmp,Cell[StyleData[x_,y___],z__],∞];
NotebookClose[nb];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[estilos]]
```

*style1.nb* is my own style with 1 style cell per type of cell

[image]