# Formatting of exporting

Tags: output-formatting, stylesheet

I am writing notes via Mathematica, but when I want to share it with others, there exists two problems.

First, if I export it as pdf, there is no word wrapping of math expression:
[image]
and input code:
[image]
we can find there exist a cut in the boundary.

Then, I want to share .nb/.cdf directly. But others will find the messy typography since they do not have my customized stylesheet.

So I want to know some methods which can deal with these problems or share my notes to others perfect.

Comment: Can you include the stylesheet buried in the notebook in some fashion? In some initialization blocks or the-like?

Comment: There is a related question [here][1]. 
[1]: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7779/how-can-i-easily-eliminate-the-dependency-of-a-stylesheet-on-a-non-built-in-styl

Comment: It is not clear how did you obtain your formulas, since in Mma there are several methods enabling this. I use at least two standard ones, and I can usually obtain the pdf file with no problem. So it is a good idea to explain in detail the method you write formulae. Further, the simplest method of sharing the nb and cdf files is either to use the built-in StyleSheets, or alternatively, to send the StyleSheet together with the file. There is a way to quench the StyleSheet into the file that you send, but it is more complex, and I recommend against it, unless it is absolutely necessary.