# How to set a background color for a cell style via a command?

Tags: front-end, formatting, stylesheet

I want to set different background colors for various cell styles (e.g. Section, Text), so that whenever I choose a specific style for some cell in the notebook, it automatically gets colored accordingly. Is this possible to do via evaluating a single simple command inside the notebook?

I've tried, for example, `Cell[StyleData["Text"], Background -> Gray]`, but it doesn't work at all. Is there a way to use SetOptions for this?

Comment: There are dozens of of questions relating to setting the background colors of cells.  Check them by searching on `cell background color`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes, I believe I've read through all the relevant ones, but I still couldn't make it work as described in the question... And thank you for the intro!

Comment: @bbgodfrey Say, I can write ```SetOptions[#, Background -> Blue] & /@ 
 Cells[CellStyle -> "Section"]```, but it needs to be evaluated every time the new Section cell is created.

Comment: You may need to create a `private stylesheet` to accomplish this, because it appears that defined styles from the Default stylesheet, when being entered, override your command, `SetOptions[#, Background -> Gray] & /@ Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], CellStyle -> "Text"]`.  Only after they are entered into your Notebook does your command apply when executed later.  Warning: I am no expert on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undoubtedly, there are commands to specify background colors for `Default` styles, but I found creating `Private Style Definitions` to be easy and convenient.  With an open notebook, open the `Format` menu and choose `Edit Stylesheet ...` to create

[image]

Then choose styles from the dropdown menu at the left and format them from the `Format` menu, in this case by choosing `Background` colors.  For instance,

[image]

To save the result, choose `Install Stylesheet` at the right and follow the instructions.  Then, close the notebook.  In the future, when opening a notebook, open the `Format` menu, choose `Stylesheet`, and select the private stylesheet created earlier.  Styles will have the backgrounds as defined, for instance.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It's probably the most convenient way after all. Do you know if the created stylesheets get saved as files? I wanted to delete the ones I've created but couldn't find them by name anywhere.

Comment: @AMA Following the advice [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7780/1063), I executed `$UserBaseDirectory`, went to that directory, and then to subdirectory `/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/`, which contains the private stylesheet, which can be deleted.  Note that the name of the private stylesheet remains in the `Format > Stylesheet` menu, and I do not know how to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command which makes the whole notebook light gray. But I don't know how to change the background of a single cell.
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Background -> LightGray]