# How can I change the default color of the basic geometric regions in 2D?

Tags: graphics, regions, options, default

I like to use the basic geometric regions in Mathematica, like `Parallelogram[...]`, `Rectangle[...]`, `Circle[...]`, but I don't like the default solid black color that Mathematica uses when I show the 2D-regions with `Graphics[Triangle[]]`.

I like the color for the 3D-regions (light brown/orange), is there a way to use this (or another) color as the default color to the 2D regions?

Comment: Graphics[{Orange,Disk[]}]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Note that the color of `Graphics3D[{Cone[]}]` is white that is shaded according to the `Lighting`. (See `FrontFaceColor /. CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Graphics3D"}]` and compare with `FrontFaceColor /. CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Graphics"}]`.  There is also `BackFaceColor`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the 2d graphics default (here, to `Red`), use

```
SetOptions[Graphics, BaseStyle -> Red];
```

Then,

```
Graphics[Triangle[]]
```

[image]

Subsequent commands, like `Graphics[Circle[]]`, also yield `Red` images by default.  Many other default options also can be set in the same way.  Remove the `;` from the first command to see them.

On the other hand, if you wish this default to persist across Notebooks, you must edit a`StyleSheet`, along the lines of my answer to [246885](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/246941/1063)

Comment: You could also use `SetOptions[Graphics, 
  BaseStyle -> {"PolygonBoxOptions" -> {BaseStyle -> {Red}}}]` for a more targeted approach.

Answer (score 0):

See `Graphics`:

[image]

Example follows giving a number of ways to set the color
(not certain one can set the "Default" color, but someone else may comment):

```
Graphics[{#, Triangle[]}] & /@ {
  CMYKColor[1, 0, 1, 0, .5],
  CMYKColor[0.3, 1, 0, .25],
  Lighter[CMYKColor[0, 0, 1, 0], .4],
  CMYKColor[0, 0, 1, 0],
  Darker[CMYKColor[0, 0, 1, 0], .4],
  RGBColor[1, 0, 0],
  Blend[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}],
  RGBColor[0, 0, 1],
  Hue[0.25, 1, 1, .5],
  Hue[0.5, 1, 1, .5]
  }
```

[image]

You can also do things like the following:

```
Graphics[{
   CMYKColor[1, 0, 1, 0, .5], 
   PatternFilling["Checkerboard"],
   Triangle[]}]
```

[image]