# Is there any other built-in color scheme for highlighting text?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Blue variable name and black key words seem boring to me now. I find that the color scheme of this site is better. Can I apply that in my notebook?

Comment: FYI, the syntax highlighter in this site is extremely limited compared to the Mathematica front end. You can customize the colors of the built-in syntax highlighter in the menu: Edit > Preferences... > Appearance > Syntax coloring.

Comment: @IstvánZachar But I don't know which color I shall use. I want a recommended scheme.

Comment: There are some finetuned color schemes (e.g. [Solarize](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized)), but no ready-made one-click file (at least I know of) that applies it to your _Mathematica_ front-end.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Thanks, anyway.

Comment: There are many Mathematica color schemes available in the stylesheet. Go to Format->Stylesheet and browse till you find one that suits your needs, or make up your own.

Comment: @bills Does a stylesheet affect the syntax highlighter as well? If so, I didn't know about that!

Comment: Related: [High Contrast Syntax-Highlighting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22519/high-contrast-syntax-highlighting), [Is it possible to change the colors of the highlighted code in the Mathematica frontend?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5930/is-it-possible-to-change-the-colors-of-the-highlighted-code-in-the-mathematica-f/5932#5932)

Comment: Here's the tutorial: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/AutomaticTextStylingFeatures.html which points to Preferences->Appearance and certainly looks like it includes color and highlighting.

Comment: @IstvánZachar See my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5932/5). If you like solarized, you can use the stylesheet that I created [here](https://github.com/stackmma/stylesheets/downloads) (I didn't realize it has been download > 1000 times!). For a screenshot, see the image in halirutan's question (first link). BTW, it's not a "perfect stylesheet", in that smaller details have not been fine tuned and it was written and tested in v8. Still, it might be of use as a starting point...