# Ergonomic night time reading settings

Tags: notebooks, color, display

I was wondering if *Mathematica* had a built-in ergonomically safe night time reading mode for the notebooks.  I was thinking of setting something up myself but I do not know the ergonomics/eye safety settings.

Comment: Are you talking about that [46422](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46422/5478)?

Comment: The easiest and most eye-friendly thing you can do for screen reading in low light situations is to simply lower the brightness level of your display.

Comment: @m_goldberg I agree. https://justgetflux.com/ helps too.

Comment: Thanks @Kuba , I will try 46422.