# Change default color when printing a string using Print[]

Tags: display

Background:
I'm just a hobbyist. I recently found how to change the default colors in a notebook using "Edit Stylesheet" under "Format". I am currently using my own color set up in "Appearance" under "Preferences" in conjunction with an custom stylesheet and the code

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Background -> Black];
```

(Side note, I am purposely avoiding the "ReverseColor" ability because it doesn't give me very fine control over my colors.)

Question:
When doing something along the lines of..

```
a="String length:";  
Print[a,"= ",StringLength[a]];
```

How do I get the default printed text/result to be a color other than black?

Bonus Q:
Can I do the above and also change the default background for a notebook using only the stylesheet and appearance settings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find a dark stylesheet for mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/where-can-i-find-a-dark-stylesheet-for-mathematica)

Comment: Adding system files seems a little extreme and wouldn't it affect all notebooks? I also only found ```Cell[TextData[{Cell[StyleData[All, "Printout"], Background -> GrayLevel[1]]}]];``` Which I can't get to work. If I can just change the default color for Print[] I will be happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the notebook's stylesheet and change the `Print` style.

Choose Format -> Edit Stylesheet...

Add a new cell.

Reveal the cell expression (Command-Shift-E).

Change to the following or similar:

```
Cell[StyleData["Print"], FontColor -> RGBColor[.8,.7,.2]]
```