# The dark side of Mathematica

Tags: style, stylesheet

I know that there are (at least one: [Where can I find a dark stylesheet for mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/where-can-i-find-a-dark-stylesheet-for-mathematica)) previous posts about how to change the appearance of Mathematica, but they haven't been much of a help for me.
The first set of questions are regarding style sheets. Suppose that I set up mine, or I use an already existing one (such as the one in the question above), can I enable it so that mathematica always functions based on that? Is it going to make its responsiveness slower (because it will always have to load more than the default style for its appearance)?

What I aim is changing everything into a shade of black, but also taking care for the cursor, etc properly so that they aren't hidden by the background.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with *dark* style sheets.  Isn't your question simply:  "How do I create my own style sheet and make it the default?"?

Comment: Perhaps you can auto-initiate the following function on startup: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DarkMode

Comment: Why not?  This is a cutesy title entirely out of character with this site.  It is also uninformative.  If others similarly use cutesy misleading titles, the entire site will become less useful, *especially* for non-native English speakers, who have no idea what your title refers to.  None.  (By the way, I'm the world's expert on the HAL 9000 computer, as you can confirm by a simple Google search on my book **HAL's Legacy**, documentary film on HAL, and innumerable lectures on HAL.)