# What is the black-background Mathematica code editor in the movie Arrival?

Tags: front-end, animation, editing

The heroine in the movie Arrival uses Mathematica to analyze the alien text. In a scene of the movie we can see the heroine is using an editor with black background, the code seems like Mathemaitca code but the editor doesn't seem to be Mathematica. So what do you think it is?
[image]

Comment: related: [Where can I find a dark stylesheet for mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46422/5478)

Comment: Also see:  https://blog.wolfram.com/2017/01/31/analyzing-and-translating-an-alien-language-arrival-logograms-and-the-wolfram-language/

Comment: Related [Dracula theme](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DraculaTheme).

Comment: Also the Wolfram Repository Function (WFR) [`DarkMode`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DarkMode). (Which is hard to find using WFR's search interface.)

Comment: Maybe, the ideal answer of this question is a Wolfram Repository Function entry that changes notebooks to the Arrival demos (notebooks) style(s). For example, `ArrivalMovieTheme`.

Comment: It would be great to know what method of achieving the dark background/theme exactly was used in the movie.

Comment: To me the black background window looks like a command terminal being used to edit Mathematica code or alternatively Wolfram Language code to be run with WolframScript.

Comment: Format -> Stylesheet -> Reverse Color essentially enables dark mode