# Quick way to preview and tweak styles?

Tags: style, stylesheet, coding-style, boxes

I find the old stylesheet UI clunky and hard to use:

```
FrontEndExecute @ FrontEndToken @ "EditStyleDefinitions"
```

[image]

There's also the clunky style previewer as well:

[image]

Without using the above, I'd like to programmatically quickly tweak and preview styled expressions and definitions for named styles. For example, let's try copying `"Entity"` and renaming it `"MyRoundedFrameStyle"` giving it different colors and frame properties:

```
CellPrint @ Cell[BoxData[
    TemplateBox[{"\"United States\"", , , "country"}, "Entity"]], 
  "Input"]
```

[image]

**What I've tried:**

Here's some code to get started:

```
DynamicModule[{x = ""}, TextGrid[{{"Input", "Output"}, 
    {InputField[Dynamic[x], String, ContinuousAction -> True],           
    Dynamic[DisplayForm[Check[DisplayForm@ToExpression[x], "-"]]]}}, 
   Alignment -> Center, Dividers -> All]]
```

Obviously, it doesn't work well:

[image]

**Notes:**

- Being able to do this inline and programmatically within a notebook would "be best" ;)
- I haven't seen any [ResourceFunction](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/search/?i=style) that could help here...
- Perhaps there are some undocumented symbols that let one ergonomically copy-and-tweak (predefined cell or box) styles for quick reuse?
- If nothing like this exists, `StylePlayground` would be a good name!

Comment: to view the style definition for the style `"stylename"` you can use `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions,"stylename"}]`

Comment: I’ve got code that does this which I use to develop my stylesheet. Basically you can find the stylesheet notebook for the notebook of interest in `NotebookInformation` and then you can use standard notebook programming to modify style definitions. After you’ve modified you then need to use the `"ToggleShowExpression"` token on the cells of interest to get the changes to load.

Comment: That could work, would be nice to see changes live somehow tho

Comment: It is relatively straight forward to build your own dynamic style creator as per: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/defining-functions-in-stylesheets/7744#7744

Comment: @M.R. I just create a test-notebook that links to my stylesheet and play with it there. I can give an example.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Can you provide a link to it?

Answer (score 3):

Here's my preferred way to do this. First we'll make some template:

```
Options[createPreviewNotebookTemplate] =
    {
       "Styles" -> {
             "Title", "Subtitle", "Chapter",
             "Section", "Subsection", "Subsubsection",
             "Text", "Code", "Input", "Output",
             "Item", "ItemNumbered", "ItemParagraph",
             "Subitem", "SubitemNumbered", "SubitemParagraph",
             "InlineFormula", "DisplayFormula", "Program"
           },
       "StyleContentMap" -> {
           "Code" -> BoxData, 
           "Input" -> BoxData, 
           "Output" -> BoxData,
           _ -> Identity
           }
       };
createPreviewNotebookTemplate[ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=

 With[{map = OptionValue["StyleContentMap"]},
      Notebook[
         Map[Cell[(# /. map)[#], #] &, OptionValue["Styles"]]
         ]
      ]

nb = CreateDocument@createPreviewNotebookTemplate[]
```

[image]

Then you can load a package I've had on my GitHub for a while and play with the styling:

```
Get["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/master/StylesheetEdit.wl"]

(*StyleSheetNew[nb, "Title"]*) (* you only want this one time, before you start adding edits *)
StyleSheetEdit[nb, "Title",
 {
   FontColor -> Pink
  }
 ]

(*StyleSheetNew[nb, "Notebook"]*)
StyleSheetEdit[nb, "Notebook",
 {
   Background -> GrayLevel[.9]
  }
 ]
```

You can also revert edits:

```
StyleSheetDelete[nb, "Notebook"]
```

This is affecting the actual stylesheet notebook that `nb` uses, not continuously writing to `StyleDefinitions`. If `nb` were a stylesheet notebook in and of itself the changes will be applied to all notebooks that depend on that sheet.

E.g. we can get the sheet for a given notebook via:

```
defaultSheet =
 Lookup[NotebookInformation[EvaluationNotebook[]], "StyleDefinitions"][[1]]
```

Then when I do:

```
StyleSheetEdit[defaultSheet, "Notebook",
 {
   Background -> GrayLevel[.9]
  }
 ]
```

every notebook that uses `"Default.nb"` will get a gray background.

We can revert that *without deleting the cell* by

```
StyleSheetEdit[defaultSheet, "Notebook",
 {
   Background -> Inherited
  }
 ]
```