# How can I use "Save as (html)" and still render code as text?

Tags: export, html

I use notebook "Save as ... (html)" to convert my .nb to web. Formulas and plots get converted to images, which is fine. But code (input cells) get converted too into images. I would like people to be able to copy and paste my code, what can I do?

Not sure how to use (in a generic scenario) what is mentioned in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/exporting-notebook-to-html-using-conversion-rules).

**edit**
Got something very close working:

```
  Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "/test.html", 
    EvaluationNotebook[], "HTML",
    "ConvertReverseClosed" -> True,
    "ConversionRules" -> {"Input" -> {"<code>", DisplayForm[#] &, 
     "</code>"}}]
```

if someone can improve on this it will be awesome.

**second edit**

This is the code I now have in a Palette. The context of the question is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15038/notebook-manipulation-to-save-as-html). The code above is now in the proper place to export to HTML, including the CDFs, in (* 1 *).

```
PaletteNotebook[
 Button[Style["Blog it", 12, FontFamily -> "Times"],
  Module[{
    nb = InputNotebook[],
    fpath = NotebookDirectory[InputNotebook[]],
    htmlName = 
     StringDrop[NotebookFileName[InputNotebook[]], -3] <> ".html",
    generateCDF,
    generateCDFs,
    exportHTML
    },
   generateCDF[nb_, name_] := Module[{sel},
     sel = SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
     Message[generateCDF::info, name];
     Export[
      FileNameJoin[{fpath, name}],
      Notebook[{NotebookRead[nb]}],
      "CDF"];
     SelectionMove[nb, "Input", Next, CellStyle]
     ];
   generateCDF::info = "Generating CDF `1`";
   generateCDFs[nb_] := Module[{sel, curID},
     SelectionMove[nb, Before, Notebook];
     sel = NotebookFind[nb, "Input", Next, CellStyle];
     While[ MatchQ[sel, _NotebookSelection],
      curID = CurrentValue[sel, CellID];
      sel = Switch[CurrentValue[sel, CellTags],
        _String, generateCDF[nb, CurrentValue[sel, CellTags]],
        _, NotebookFind[nb, "Input", Next, CellStyle]
        ];
      ];
     ];
   exportHTML[nb_] := Module[{
      rules = {
        "Input" -> {
          "\n<pre class=\"code\">\n",
          DisplayForm[#] &,
          "\n</pre>\n"
          } (* 1 *)
        }
      },
     Message[exportHTML::info, FileNameTake[htmlName]];
     Export[
      htmlName,
      nb,
      "HTML",
      "CSS" -> None,
      "MathOutput" -> "GIF",
      "ConvertReverseClosed" -> True,
      "ConversionRules" -> rules
      ];
     Message[exportHTML::done];
     ];

   exportHTML::info = "Generating HTML `1`";
   exportHTML::done = "Export to HTML done";
   generateCDFs[nb];
   exportHTML[nb];
   ],
  Appearance -> "Palette"]
 ]
```

The problem I have is that it generates funny characters in the HTML. I have tried several "encoding" options without luck. This is an example of what I get:

[image: web page screenshot]

I am not worried about the tags or formatting as I know how to deal with those in my Rails app or in CSS. But the "wrongly encoded" characters are my issue. I committed the sample.nb and sample palette code to [github](https://github.com/carlosayam/mathematica-blog/tree/master/mathematica) if any one wants to test it.

Comment: Good question. I'd also like to know how one can implement the functionality of the mathematica online documentation, where the input cells are images and then one can click on the image and a box with copyable code appears.

Comment: I think the online documentation is built using [Mathematica Workbench](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/topic/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/documentationpaclets/index.html)

Comment: Any news on the project? It seems the project has not been updated for 3 years.

Answer (score 4):

This stupid piece of code doesn't work very well:

```
Export["test.xhtml",  EvaluationNotebook[], "MathOutput" → "DisplayForm"]
```

and crashes Mathematica 8 reliably too, but the files it creates contain selectable text - here selecting something in the browser...

[image]

Comment: Thanks cormullion. I was thinking on something along those lines. I got the following not crashing... Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "/test.html", 
 EvaluationNotebook[], "HTML",
 "ConvertReverseClosed" -> True,
 "ConversionRules" -> {"Input" -> {"<p class=\"text\">\n", # &, "\n</p>"}}] but produces lots of RowBox[...] output, so I bet I need to convert from RowBox to plain text somehow.

Comment: @caya Have you tried _exactly_ what cormullion recommends? It works on my machine (for some reason, I had to replace his arrow with my `->`, though).

Comment: @VF1, hum, not *exactly* as I have more options to supply and was trying "HTML" instead "XHTML". I will give it another go. If it works will be more than happy to accept answer. Tnx

Comment: @VF1, that approach crashes consistently. The best I can do is to convert to HTML as mentioned in my first edit, but still the special characters are not properly mapped.

Comment: Your first line sounds like a mantra for a lot of my code (as well as the "but it works after a fashion anyhow" part) :-)

Comment: @yves thank god I'm not the only one then :)

Comment: Hi,Why, I have these errors? and $Failed?Export::noelem: MathOutput\[RightArrow]DisplayForm is not a valid set of export elements for the HTML format. >>

Comment: @HyperGroups Looks like the `→` is interpreted by mma as `\[RightArrow]`, try using `->` (`\[Rule]`) instead.