# How to grab CellTags from a Cell?

Tags: options, palettes, html

I am in the process of creating a palette for a specialised "Save as HTML". For context please see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15038/notebook-manipulation-to-save-as-html).

How can I grab the CellTags from a Cell[...] object? This is my first iteration, aka testing code:

```
PaletteNotebook[
 Module[{action, create},
  create := NotebookCreate[];
  action[nb_] := Module[{found, out, cell},
    out = create;
    SelectionMove[nb, Before, Notebook];
    found = NotebookFind[nb, "Input", Next, CellStyle];
    If[found != $Failed,
     cell = NotebookRead[nb];
     NotebookWrite[out, OptionValue[cell, CellTags]] (* 1 *),
     NotebookWrite[out, "Not found"]
     ];
    ];
  Button[Style["Blog it", 12, FontFamily -> "Times"],
   action[InputNotebook[]],
   Appearance -> "Palette"]
  ]
 ]
```

At the moment it just dumps data into a temporary empty notebook if it finds the Input cell, but the code at (* 1 *) does not print the CellTags the cell has in the `InputNotebook[]`. I am thinking that `OptionsPattern[]` may be the answer, but I am not sure how to use it. I tried

```
...
cell = NotebookRead[nb];
tags = cell /. Cell[__, OptionsPattern[]] :> OptionValue[CellTags];
NotebookWrite[out, tags],
...
```

but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Oh dear, @Rojo posted an answer and got removed in few mins! Why?

Comment: He did it himself. May have been a bug in it or so.

Comment: Actually it worked. However @Rojo himself gave +1 to Albert's, so I just accepted that one... "Why?" A mystery :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already have the selection set to the cell and `NotebookFind` returns that selection, you could just use `CurrentValue` on it as here:

```
PaletteNotebook[
 Button[Style["Blog it", 12, FontFamily -> "Times"],
  Module[{
    nb = InputNotebook[],
    out = NotebookCreate[],
    retval
    },
   SelectionMove[nb, Before, Notebook];
   retval = NotebookFind[nb, "Input", Next, CellStyle];
   NotebookWrite[out,
    Switch[retval,
     _NotebookSelection, CurrentValue[retval, CellTags],
     _, "Not found"
     ]
    ]
   ],
  Appearance -> "Palette"
  ]
 ]
```

as already mentionend [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6585/169) I'd strongly suggest to read [the joy of tagging](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7246/) if you intend to do more advanced work with `CellTags`, which seems to be a reasonable idea for what you plan.

Comment: Albert, the answer is more *Mathematica* style, thanks. I will have a look a the pointer.