# "Save as (html)" and still render Input cell code as text?

Tags: export, html

[When I' m testing on this post' s method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13237/how-can-i-use-save-as-html-and-still-render-code-as-text/30892#30892)

I found some problems.

```
Export["test.html", nb = EvaluationNotebook[], "HTML",  
    "ConversionRules" -> {"Input" -> {"<pre><code>", DisplayForm[#] &, "/code>/pre>"}},
    CharacterEncoding -> "CP936", "CSS" -> None]


Export["test.html", nb = EvaluationNotebook[], "HTML",  
     "ConversionRules" -> {"Input" -> {"<pre><code>", InputForm[#] &, "</code>/pre>"}},  
     CharacterEncoding -> "CP936", "CSS" -> None]
```

[image]

How can I keep the Codes completely the same as that in the Notebook?

Are there any easy ways to do that? For example, change the `DisplayFormula[#]&` into something else that I don't know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This thing could be done by the option `"MathOutput"->"InputForm"`, However I'm not sure whether this can entirely solve the question(need more tests).

```
Export["test.html", nb = EvaluationNotebook[], "HTML",  
       "ConversionRules" -> {"Input" -> {"<pre><code>", "</code></pre>"}}, 
       CharacterEncoding -> "CP936", "CSS" -> None,"MathOutput"->"InputForm"]
```

[image]

Merge two `Input Cell`（Or type by <kbd>Enter</kbd>, there is a `"\n"` in the cell Expression）, and follow the method in the above then still generate images in the `HTML` files. (How to make this `Input Cell` become text in the html files?)

[image]

Comment: I have resized last image, feel free to undo this if you like.