# Export as HTML: Render Manipulate as an image, not a CDF

Tags: manipulate, export, html

When I Export a notebook to HTML, Mathematica renders each Manipulate GUI as an object that requires the CDF browser plugin. For example, this notebook:

[image]

... renders to this webpage:

[image]

How can I tell Export to convert the Manipulate cells to images instead of CDFs?

Perhaps `ConversionRules` is needed, as in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13237/how-can-i-use-save-as-html-and-still-render-code-as-text) answer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `ManipulateOutput` option:

```
Export["...filename", EvaluationNotebook[], "ManipulateOutput" -> "PNG"]
```

Please see more details about [`HTML format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HTML.html) if you need to tweak it.

Comment: More clarifications please!!