# After NumberForm I cannot apply a Sine function. Why?

Tags: equation-solving, evaluation

After NumberForm I cannot apply a Sine function. Why?

This works:

```
sol1 = x /. Solve[x^2 - 3 == 0, x]
Sin[sol1]
```

Output = $\{-Sin[\sqrt{3}],Sin[\sqrt{3}]\}$

Also this works:

```
sol2 = x /. Solve[x^2 - 3 == 0, x] // N
Sin[sol2]
```

Output = $\{-0.987027,0.987027\}$

Then why doesn't this work? Meaning, why is Sin[] not applied to the elements of the list?

```
sol3 = NumberForm[x /. Solve[x^2 - 3 == 0, x] // N, 6]
Sin[sol3]
```

Output = $Sin[\{-1.73205,1.73205\}]$

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Point nr. 8 [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/731) is relevant.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) to see the differences

```
sol3 = NumberForm[x /. Solve[x^2-3 == 0, x]//N, 6]
(* {-1.73205,1.73205} *)
```

This definition includes the `NumberForm` wrapper that was intended just for printing.

```
sol3//FullForm
(* NumberForm[List[-1.7320508075688772`,1.7320508075688772`],6] *)
```

Alternatively, use [`Information`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Information.html) to look at the stored definition

```
?sol3
(* Global`sol3
sol3=NumberForm[{-1.73205,1.73205},6] *)
```

Consequently, the input to `Sin` is neither numeric nor a `List` of numeric values

```
Sin[sol3]//FullForm
(* Sin[NumberForm[List[-1.7320508075688772`,1.7320508075688772`],6]] *)
```

You could `Map` the `Sin` to the appropriate level

```
Map[Sin,sol3,{2}]//FullForm
(* NumberForm[List[-0.9870266449903538`,0.9870266449903538`],6] *)
```

However, the common approach is to put the wrapper outside the definition

```
NumberForm[sol32=x/.Solve[x^2-3==0,x]//N,6]//FullForm
(* NumberForm[List[-1.7320508075688772`,1.7320508075688772`],6] *)
```

However, you have to use `NumberForm` again if you want the output of `Sin` to also be formatted with `NumberForm`

```
Sin[sol32]//FullForm
(* List[-0.9870266449903538`,0.9870266449903538`] *)

NumberForm[Sin[sol32],6]//FullForm
(* NumberForm[List[-0.9870266449903538`,0.9870266449903538`],6] *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NumberForm[N[x /. Solve[x^2 - 3 == 0, x]], 6]

Sin[%]

(* {-1.73205,1.73205} *)

(* {-0.987027, 0.987027}*)
```

Comment: The first input needs to  be evaluated before you apply Sine function, therefore use Sin[%]

Comment: Hmm, interesting. But why isn't the Sin applied directly when I do Sin[sol3]?

Comment: Yeah, what is going on here?  This doesn't answer the question of "Why?" at all.  Taking `Sin[sol3]` doesn't get evaluated.  But typing `sol3;Sin[%]`  does.  So what gives?

Comment: @thils On my computer (MMA 10.2 Win7-64) running your code outputs `Sin[{-1.73205,1.73205}]`, not the values you show. How did you generate this behavior?

Comment: @MarcoB pls delete ";" , have edited this bit. Numberform attributes are described in the manual.

Comment: @JasonB [(44189)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44189/121)