# Why does Transpose not work after I wrap a list with NumberForm?

Tags: functions, core-language

This code works fine.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] = x^3 + 2 x^2 - 2;
Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 4}]
guess = 1.4;
iter = 10;
n = Table[j, {j, 0, iter}];
xn = NestList[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, guess, iter];
Grid[Transpose[{n, xn}], Frame -> All]
```

But when I add `NumberForm` suddenly `Transpose` doesn't work anymore. I have no clue why this is and how to fix it. Any ideas?

This is the code with `NumberForm`.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] = x^3 + 2 x^2 - 2;
Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 4}]
guess = 1.4;
iter = 10;
n = Table[j, {j, 0, iter}];
xn = NumberForm[NestList[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, guess, iter], {∞, 10}];
Grid[Transpose[{n, xn}], Frame -> All]
```

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92889/5478

Comment: @Kuba Next time you find a duplicate (original) that is itself closed, please Flag the post rather than or in addition to commenting, for moderator attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Transpose` only takes a list of lists as it 1st argument.

```
Transpose[{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}]
```

> `{{a, d}, {b, e}, {c, f}}`

```
Transpose[{{a, b, c}, f[{d, e, f}]}]
```

> `Transpose[{{a, b, c}, f[{d, e, f}]}]`

`NumberForm` is just another head like `f`.

```
Transpose[{{a, b, c}, NumberForm[{d, e, f}, {∞, 10}]}] // FullForm
```

> ```
> Transpose[
>   List[List[a, b, c], NumberForm[List[d, e, f], List[DirectedInfinity[1], 10]]]]
> ```

Just because the head `NumberForm` doesn't normally print in output doesn't mean it's not there. The work-around is to map `NumberForm` over the elements of `{d, e, f}`.

```
Transpose[{{a, b, c}, NumberForm[#, {∞, 10}] & /@ {d, e, f}}]
```

> `{{a, d}, {b, e}, {c, f}}`

```
% // FullForm
```

> ```
> List[
>     List[a, NumberForm[d, List[DirectedInfinity[1], 10]]], 
>     List[b, NumberForm[e, List[DirectedInfinity[1], 10]]], 
>     List[c, NumberForm[f, List[DirectedInfinity[1], 10]]]]
> ```

Comment: I think perhaps this question should be merged with [(92885)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92885/121) as it is essentially the same question by the same author.  I would likely require some rewriting of that question to include the `Transpose` case, but I think this would be more useful for future readers.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Are you asking me to do something? I don't understand what merging two questions involves. Further, I ask why the linking of the two questions as duplicates, which you have already done, isn't good enough for archival purposes?

Comment: Sorry, let me try to clarify.  A merge permanently moves all Answers from one Question to another.  To make the "new" answers fit either they (or the question itself) often need some editing.  So I was asking (1) Do you agree that a merge would be beneficial? (2) If "yes" to the first are you willing to do the editing?  It sounds like a "no" to the first so I'll leave this as it is.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I think I need further discussion before proceeding. I don't do chat very well because I have great difficulty typing at the speed others seem to expect. Could we do it by email? I have an address for you from last year. I will contact you that way if you indicate it would be OK.

Comment: Yes, that is fine, and I am happy to discuss it if you like, but at the same time I did not mean to pressure you in any way.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Not feeling any pressure since I haven't agreed to do anything so far. Email forthcoming.