# How to switch a number back from AccountingForm?

Tags: number-representation

I am working with a function that returns output in `AccountingForm` format. I would like to do math with that output, but Mathematica does not recognize it as numbers. Is there a way to convert a number in `AccountingForm` back into a real number?

```
x1 = 23.3;
x2 = AccountingForm[x1];
2*x2 (* does not compute *)
```

various things I have tried . . .

```
2*NumberForm[x2, 2] (* does not compute *)

2*N[x2, 2] (* does not compute *)

2*Apply[Real, x2] (* does not compute *)

2*ToExpression[x2] (* does not compute *)
```

Thanks

Comment: You can just do `x2=x2[[1]]` which gets rid of the `AccountingForm` head.

Comment: closely related: [7871](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7871/5478)

Comment: is that a good duplicate: [After NumberForm I cannot apply a Sine function. Why?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92885/5478)?

Comment: @N.J.Evans That's a perfectly good answer. If you post it as such, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Kuba It's a related issue but to my eye it is not the same question.

Comment: all the `*Form` format functions raise the same issue, so it really is the same essential question.  The best answer really is don't do that in the first place..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the number from the `AccountingForm` head, as per [PartsOfExpressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PartsOfExpressions.html) (which may address some shortcomings that I'm forgetting to mention), by extracting the first part using any alias for that operation:

```
x=AccountingForm[3.14];
x=x[[1]]
```

or `x=First@x`,
or `x=Part[x,1]`