# Classification of Forms and understanding what goes into \$PrintForms, \$OutputForms, Out[x]//XXXForm=, and what does not

Tags: formatting

Mathematica has lots of Forms. Some of those appear in `$PrintForms`, like `InputForm`, `OutputForm`, `CForm` and so on, but some Forms do not, like `ScientificForm`, and `StringForm` or `HornerForm`.

What distinguishes when something goes into `$PrintForms` and what doesn't?

*Edit:* As noted in the comment, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73539/1871 mentions there is also `$OutputForms` which seems to include more things than `$Printforms`. In particular it contains `ScientificForm`, but not `StringForm` or `HornerForm`.

What is the difference between these `$PrintForms` and `$OutputForms`?

In https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TextualInputAndOutput.html#12368 I read:

> It is important to understand that in a typical Wolfram Language session `In[n]` and `Out[n]` record only the underlying expressions that are processed, not the textual representations that happen to be used for their input or output.
>
> If you explicitly request a particular kind of output, say by using TraditionalForm[expr], then what you get will be labeled with `Out[n]//TraditionalForm`. This indicates that what you are seeing is `expr//TraditionalForm`, even though the value of `Out[n]` itself is just expr.

I note that `StringForm` and `HornerForm` do not work that way though. Is there guide to understanding what will be marked `Out[n]//XXXForm` and what won't?

More generally, are there natural classes of forms? Two kinds suggested above are: those that are in `$PrintForms`, `$OutputForms`, those that appear as `//XXForm` in output, and others.

However these might be quirky and there might be other more natural classifications of Form functions.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73539/1871