# How to sort arguments of Times in nonstandard order?

Tags: output-formatting, algebraic-manipulation

Is there an elegant way to sort the arguments of `Times` in e.g. `TraditionalForm` so that factors go to the front and state variables to the back? Are there methods to prevent certain transformations, like moving everything into the numerator as in the example?

```
par = {p, k, Subscript[k, a], Subscript[k, b]};
expr = -A Subscript[k, b] B p k (1 - p) 1/(B + A) Subscript[k, a]
```

$-\frac{A \ B \ k \ (1-p) \ p \ k_a \ k_b}{A+B}$

What I would like to see is that symbols are ordered according to their appearance order in `par`, symbols not specified are sent to the back and fractions are not transformed at all, something like this:

$-(1-p) \ p \ k \ k_a \ k_b \ \frac{1}{A+B} \ A \ B$

There are many problems when manually sorting arguments of `Times` (here I only did a reversal for sake of simplicity):

```
expr /. Times[x_, y__] :> ((Inactive@Times) @@ Reverse[{x, y}])
```

$k_b*k_a*p*(1-p)*k*\frac{1}{A+B}*B*A*-1$

for example unnecessary `*`-s and numerical factors like -1 explicitly displayed.

Comment: Interesting question, but I have the feeling we had one like this before. Can't find it at the moment, though.

Comment: @Sjoerd I had the same feeling, and you can imagine that I took the time to look for it. BTW, I find it very strange that a complex typesetting environment like _Mathematica_ does not provide this functionality readily and one has to hack his way like jkuczm did...

Comment: Related: [(9570)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9570/121)

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Wizard, that is the one I was looking for. Accordingly, mine is a duplicate then.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Wait! On second thought, I ask for more time to evaluate the differences. One of my concerns (not worded above) was that the output must be readily convertible by `TeXForm` and I'm not sure `Row`-s in Silvia's answer are ok with TeX. Will check it tomorrow all your answers, have to sleep now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create [your own `...Form` wrapper](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51898/14303) that will format `Times` as you want it.

Let's start with ordering function that can be used in `SortBy`. It puts numeric coefficients in front, expressions present in `par` are ordered according to their position in `par`, all other expressions are moved to the end.

```
ClearAll[par, order]
par = {(1 - p), p, k, Subscript[k, a], Subscript[k, b]};
order[_?NumericQ] := 0
order[x_] := Replace[Position[par, x, {1}, 1], {{i_}} :> i]
```

Now a small helper "wrapper" that will vanish after conversion to boxes. It will also remove boxes resulting from `HoldForm` used directly inside wrapper.

```
ClearAll[vanishingWrapper]
MakeBoxes[vanishingWrapper[expr_], form_] ^:= MakeBoxes[expr, form];
MakeBoxes[vanishingWrapper[HoldForm[expr_]], form_] ^:= 
    First@MakeBoxes[HoldForm[expr], form];
```

Now the main `...Form` function that, when converted to boxes, wraps some sub-expressions with our `vanishingWrapper`:

```
ClearAll[istvanForm]
MakeBoxes[istvanForm[expr_], _] ^:=
    With[
        {heldExpr =
            HoldComplete[expr] /. HoldPattern[Times][args__] :>
                With[
                    {eval =
                        With[
                            {heldArgs = 
                                Replace[
                                    SortBy[HoldComplete[args], order], 
                                    pow_Power :> vanishingWrapper[pow],
                                    {1}
                                ]}
                            ,
                            Function[Null,
                                vanishingWrapper@HoldForm@Times[##], 
                                HoldAllComplete
                            ] @@ heldArgs
                        ]}
                    ,
                    eval /; True
                ]}
        ,
        Function[Null, MakeBoxes[#, TraditionalForm], HoldAllComplete] @@
            heldExpr
    ]
```

When `Times` function is converted to `TraditionalForm` boxes, its arguments are sorted, unless `Times` is inside `HoldForm`. This sorting is done in addition to ordinary sorting, occurring due to `Orderless` attribute, when `Times` is evaluated. To prevent this additional sorting, `istvanForm` wraps `Times` with `HoldForm` and `vanishingWrapper`. So we get boxes coming from `HoldForm[Times[...]]`, but thanks to `vanishingWrapper` all additional boxes from `HoldForm` are gone, so when we copy resulting expression there will be no `HoldForm` inside it.

When `Power` expression, with negative numeric exponent, is found directly inside `Times`, it triggers special formatting rules putting everything in one fraction. To prevent this special formatting, `istvanForm` wraps all `Power` expressions on first level of `Times` with `vanishingWrapper`. So that, when expression is converted to boxes, special formatting is not triggered.

To make `istvanForm` behave like proper `...Form` wrapper we must add it to `$OutputForms`:

```
If[FreeQ[$OutputForms, #, {1}],
Unprotect@$OutputForms;
    PrependTo[$OutputForms, #];
Protect@$OutputForms;
]& @ istvanForm
```

Now let's see `istvanForm` in action:

```
-A Subscript[k, b] B p k (1 - p) 1/(B + A) Subscript[k, a] // istvanForm
```

[image: istvanForm usage]

Comment: The only occasion when a user-defined function should start with a capital letter! +1 : )

Comment: @IstvánZachar I promise to capitalize your name next time I use it in a function ;)

Answer (score 3):

I shall adapt my code from [How do I reassign canonical ordering of symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9570/how-do-i-reassign-canonical-ordering-of-symbols/9616#9616) with the addition of a rule for the `Power[_, -1]` form.  I assume that any [`Variables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables.html) not in `par` are to be placed at the end.

```
reorderIstván[expr_, par_List] :=
 Module[{h, rls},
   rls = MapIndexed[x : # :> h[#2, Replace[x, rls, -1]] &, 
     DeleteDuplicates @ Join[par, Variables @ expr] ];
   HoldForm @@ {expr /. rls} //. h[_, x_] :> x /. 
    x_^-1 :> RawBoxes @ FractionBox["1", ToBoxes[x]]
 ]
```

Now:

```
par = {p, k, Subscript[k, a], Subscript[k, b]};
expr = -A Subscript[k, b] B p k (1 - p) 1/(B + A) Subscript[k, a];

reorderIstván[expr, par]
```

> ```
> -(1 - p) p k Subscript[k, a] Subscript[k, b] A B 1/(A + B)
> ```

```
reorderIstván[expr, par] // TeXForm
```

> $-(1-p) p k k_a k_b A B \frac{1}{A+B}$

Comment: I got the time to advance with this problem. My issue with your approach is that due to the `HoldForm`-s, one cannot do post replacements like ``reorderIstván[expr, par] /. 
 x_Symbol :> If[Context@x === "Global`", f@x, x]``. I haven't figured a way to bypass this yet... any idea? I'd rather avoid including this transformation directly into the reordering function.

Comment: @IstvánZachar does `reorderIstván[expr, par] /. x_Symbol :> RuleCondition@If[Context@x === "Global`", f@x, x]` give what you want or are you looking for something else?  (See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29319/121 if you are unfamiliar with `RuleCondition`.)

Comment: Ok, `RuleCondition` did the job, thanks. I knew (and forgot) about it but never used before.