# MatrixForm with zeroes formatted in gray

Tags: matrix, output-formatting, formatting

I would like to define a version of `MatrixForm` that prints entries equal to zero in gray. The definition

```
matrixform[X_] := MatrixForm[X /. entry_ /; entry == 0 -> Style[0, LightGray]]
```

produces an output that looks how I'd want, but it actually changes the entries, rather than just the way they are displayed, so one cannot just use the output of my `matrixform` via `%` in algebraic manipulations.

*Ideally* I'm looking for an answer that works for sparse arrays too, without the conversion to a normal array: at least, I'd like to be able to work with the output without having to convert it back to a sparse array.

Note that I don't want just *all* zeroes in my notebook to be formatted in gray (so I don't think I can use `Format`), and I don't want matrices to be formatted as above *automatically* either.

---

*Edit.* Here is an example of what I'm hoping to achieve:

```
A = SparseArray[{1,1}->x,{2,2}]
(* Out: SparseArray[..., Specified elements: 1, Dimensions: {2,2}] as usual *) 

% // matrixform
(* Out: MatrixForm of A with 0s shown in gray *)

2 %
(* Out: SparseArray[..., Specified elements: 1, Dimensions: {2,2}] as usual *)

% // matrixform
(* Out: MatrixForm of 2*A with 0s shown in gray *)
```

Comment: PS. I don't really understand if there's a difference between the tags `output-formatting` and `formatting`, so I've used both; feel free to edit them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the `%` behavior you want, you need to create a wrapper, that is, a function that does not evaluate, but creates a nice format when it is rendered. The usual way to do this is to use [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes). Here is a version that should target only matrix entries, and also avoid evaluation leaks:

```
matrixForm /: MakeBoxes[matrixForm[x_List], StandardForm] := Replace[
    Replace[Hold[x], 0->Style[0, Red], {3}],
    Hold[z_] :> MakeBoxes[MatrixForm[z]]
]
```

Note that I used [`Red`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Red) instead of [`LightGray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LightGray) to improve visualization for this answer. Now that `matrixForm` is a wrapper, you can add it to [`$OutputForms`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$OutputForms) as suggested in [(51898)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51930/45431).

```
Unprotect[$OutputForms];
AppendTo[$OutputForms, matrixForm];
Protect[$OutputForms];
```

Example:

```
matrixForm[{{f[0], 0}, {1, 0}}]
```

[image]

And using `%`:

```
%
```

> {{f[0], 0}, {1, 0}}

For [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) objects, you could add the following format, but note that it relies on being able to reconstruct a [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) from its [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm), updated to work in M13 as well (note that being able to reconstruct a sparse array in this way may change in the future):

```
matrixForm /: MakeBoxes[matrixForm @ s_SparseArray, StandardForm] := With[
    {
    new = SparseArray[
        Automatic, 
        Dimensions[s], 
        Style[s["Background"], Red],
        {1, {s["RowPointers"], s["ColumnIndices"]}, s["NonzeroValues"]}]
    },
    MakeBoxes[
        MatrixForm @ new,
        StandardForm
    ]
]
```

Example:

```
matrixForm[IdentityMatrix[3, SparseArray]]
```

[image]

Check `%`:

```
%
```

> SparseArray[Automatic, {3, 3}, 0, {
> 1, {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {{1}, {2}, {3}}}, {1, 1, 1}}]

Comment: Very nice! Do also know how to make it work for displaying sparse arrays as well, without turning the `%` into normal form?

Comment: @JulesLamers See update

Comment: Fantastic, that does exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: In Mma v13 the part of your answer for sparse arrays no longer works. Do you know how this can be fixed?

Comment: @JulesLamers See update.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 6):

```
SeedRandom[0]

(m = RandomInteger[{0, 2}, {4, 4}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Note that by using parentheses, the definition of `m` does not include the wrapper `MatrixForm`

```
matrixForm[x_List] := ((x /. 0 :> Style[0, LightGray]) // MatrixForm)

m // matrixForm
```

[image]

The wrappers, `MatrixForm` or `matrixForm` are only for display. If you want to use the matrix, use `m`. Any subsequent operation is done on `m` and the display is formatted using the wrapper.

```
(m2 = Transpose@m) // matrixForm
```

[image]

```
m == (m2 // Transpose)

(* True *)
```

Comment: I think that does more or less what my `matrixform` does. The problem is that such definitions alter the matrix you're displaying: the line after `m // matrixform`, writing e.g. `2 %` gives {{4,4,2,2*Style[0,LightGray]},...}

Comment: Ad edit: Output formatted with `MatrixForm` can be used for algebraic manipulations. For example, starting from some sparse array `a`, even though the output of `a // MatrixForm` is nicely formatted, one can actually use that output in something like `2 %` to get a sparse array whose entries are twice those of `a`. I am looking for something similar here, perferably *without* having to use parentheses as in`(...) // matrixform`, if possible

Comment: @JulesLamers -  Then just use `2 % // matrixform`

Comment: @JulesLamers To get the % behavior you want, see [(51898)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51898/45431).

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks! That looks very relevant. (And complicated...) I'll take a better look at it later

Comment: @JulesLamers All you have to do is `Unprotect[$OutputForms]; AppendTo[$OutputForms, matrixForm]; Protect[$OutputForms];`

Comment: @CarlWoll That'd be fantastic. But unfortunately it doesn't work: `%` still yields `Style[0,LightGray]`...

Comment: @JulesLamers I forgot that `matrixForm` needs to be a wrapper. See my answer for more details.